# Fuzzy/buggy div on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, hover, fuzzy

I have following code:

```
<div id="area">
  <p>
    Area here
  </p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#area').on('mouseenter', function(event){
  $('#area').addClass('active');
});

$('#area').on('mouseleave', function(event){
  $('#area').removeClass('active');
});
```

SCSS:

```
#area{
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  background:blue;

  &.active{
    height:50px;
  }
}
```

When I hover over #area, it's changing (and should) it's height to be less than original. But when the hover action is being done from bottom of page and up to the div, the height is fuzzying around.

Video of the issue: 
https://streamable.com/phzka

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gbL50pqj/3/

This is happening because of changing the height when hover action is being made, but what is the best method to prevent the buggy part of it?
This is what I have tried:

```
$('#area').on('mouseleave', function(event){
  $('#area').stop().removeClass('active');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the events occur too fast here.

If you apply a delay to the CSS transition, it fixes that flickering.
Up to you to adjust it...

`.stop()` only has effect on jQuery animations... There is no effect on add/remove class.

```js
$('#area').on('mouseenter', function(event){
  $('#area').addClass('active');
});

$('#area').on('mouseleave', function(event){
  $('#area').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
#area{
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  background:blue;
  transition: 0.6s;  /* Transition delay */

  /* SCSS
  &.active{
    height:50px;
  }
  */
}

#area.active{  /* SCSS Equivalent for SO example */
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="area">
  <p>
    Area here
  </p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You can do it using another "transparent" `div` above the visible "area".
So the mouse enter and leave will be triggered on a `div` that does not change in height.

Below, I added a red border to it, so you can see its position.

```js
$('#area_transparent').on('mouseenter', function(event){
  $('#area').addClass('active');
});

$('#area_transparent').on('mouseleave', function(event){
  $('#area').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
#area{
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  background:blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index:1

  /* SCSS
  &.active{
    height:50px;
  }
  */
}

#area.active{  /* SCSS Equivalent for SO example */
  height:50px;
}

#area_transparent{
  height:100px;
  width:500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:100;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="area">
  <div id="area_transparent"></div>
  <p>
    Area here
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works a bit better, but it's still kind'a buggy: https://streamable.com/p2lvo. And in this case the transition effect is not the best due to the requirements :/. Is it perhaps possible to prevent this with a delay of jquery? :